# Nothing happens after Prompt

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, prompt

Sorry, I wasn't clear enough.  I need it to list all the numbers from 0 to the number inputted by the prompt into the HTML.  I made some suggested changes but now I only get the result for the specific number inputted, not all the numbers up to that number. I am just starting out so please be gentle. Thanks!

```
$(function() {

  var number = parseInt(prompt("Let me see a number:"));
  var result;

   for(var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
    if ( i %15 == 0) {
            result = "Ping-Pong";
        }
        else if (i %5 == 0) {
            result = "Pong";
        }
        else if (i %3 == 0) {
            result = "Ping";
        }
        else {
            result = number;
        }
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = result;
};
```

});

Comment: But what are you expect to see?

Comment: Where is your digit variable stated ? You're recording prompt result in 'number' variable but then for some reason you use 'digit' variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
 var digit = number[i]; // or any other assigment to new digit var

 if ( digit % 5 == 0) {
        return "Ping-Pong";
    }
.... rest of your code here.
```

or

```
 if ( number % 5 == 0) {
        return "Ping-Pong";
    }
.... rest of your code here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you did nothing after the return keyword. Also you didn't declared variable as `digit`. I hope this is what you are looking for.

With loop:

```js
$(function() {

  var number = parseInt(prompt("Let me see a number:"));
  var result;
  for (var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0) { // replaced `digit` with `i`
      result = "Ping-Pong";
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
      result = "Pong";
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
      result = "Ping";
    } else {
      result = number;
    }
    alert(result);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Without loop:

```js
$(function() {

  var number = parseInt(prompt("Let me see a number:"));
  var result;
  if (number % 15 == 0) { // replaced `digit` with `number`
    result = "Ping-Pong";
  } else if (number % 5 == 0) {
    result = "Pong";
  } else if (number % 3 == 0) {
    result = "Ping";
  } else {
    result = number;
  }
  alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  For future reference, this is what I was trying to do:

```
  $(function() {

  var number = parseInt(prompt("Let me see a number:"));
  var i
  var text = "";

for(i = 1; i <= number; i++) {


    if ( i %15 == 0) {
        text += "<br>" + "Ping Pong" + "<br>";
        }
        else if (i %5 == 0) {
        text += "<br>" + "Pong" + "<br>";
        }
        else if (i %3 == 0) {
            text += "<br>" + "Ping" + "<br>";
        }
        else {
            text += "<br>" + i + "<br>";
        }
};
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = text;
```

});